# Regex to test if string begins with http:// or https://

Tags: regex

I'm trying to set a regexp which will check the start of a string, and if it contains either `http://` or `https://` it should match it.

How can I do that? I'm trying the following which isn't working:

```
^[(http)(https)]://
```

Comment: If you're checking just the start of the string, it's probably faster to just do a straight comparison of the first few characters of the string with the patterns you're looking for.

Comment: You are creating a *character group* with `[]`. It will mach **one** character that is either `(`,`)`,`h`,`t`,`t`,`p` or `s`. I.e. it would match `s://` but not `ht://` or `x://`.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I think I sense some premature optimization.

Comment: Many modern regular expression libraries are *very fast*. Unless there is (lots of) back-tracking, regular expressions may compare favorably -- or better -- to "index-of" style approaches (compare `/^x/` vs `indexOf(x) == 0`). "starts with" style approaches may have less overhead, but I suspect it rarely matters -- choose what is the cleanest, which very well may be: `x.StartWith("http://") || x.StartsWith("https://")` -- but do so out of code clarity, not an attempt to improve performance unless justified with analysis and requirements :-)

Comment: dont forget the case of the protocol is not set like //www.google.fr

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Your use of `[]` is incorrect -- note that `[]` denotes a *character class* and will therefore only ever match one character.  The expression `[(http)(https)]` translates to "match a `(`, an `h`, a `t`, a `t`, a `p`, a `)`, or an `s`."  (Duplicate characters are ignored.)

Try this:

```
^https?://
```

If you really want to use alternation, use this syntax instead:

```
^(http|https)://
```

Comment: As a PHP input string: $regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)';

Comment: Steve, I think you missed a / at the end:  $regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)/';

Comment: Just in case some nut accidentally uppercases the http, $regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)/i';

Comment: You forgot to escape / using \. So it would be `^https?:\/\/`. Am I right?

Comment: @Shafizadeh `/` is not a special character in regular expressions, only in languages where `/` is used to notate a literal regular expression. For example, it is not necessary to escape `/` in regular expressions when using C#, because C# regular expressions are expressed (in part) as string literals. Nor do you need them in, say, Perl (when using an alternate delimiter as in `m#^https?://#`). So to directly address your comment: (a) No, I did not forget to escape anything. (b) You will need to escape whatever characters are treated specially in your language of choice.

Comment: @Shafizadeh As another counter-example, when using `grep` from the command-line, the `/` characters do not need to be escaped, but *the `?` character does!* This answer is intended to be language-neutral.

Comment: This url will validate as successful https:////m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.23.3/images/bbc-sport-logo.png. If using PHP i think https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/filter_validate_url.asp is the way to go.

Comment: Also maybe ```^(https?:\/\/[\w\d])```

Answer (score 53):

Case insensitive:

```
var re = new RegExp("^(http|https)://", "i");
var str = "My String";
var match = re.test(str);
```

Answer (score 33):

```
^https?://
```

You might have to escape the forward slashes though, depending on context.

Answer (score 33):

`^https?:\/\/(.*)` where `(.*)` is match everything else after `https://`

Answer (score 20):

This should work

```
^(http|https)://
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` for start of the string pattern,

`?` for allowing 0 or 1 time repeat. ie., `s?`  **s** can exist 1 time or no need to exist at all.

`/` is a special character in regex so it needs to be escaped by a backslash `\/`

```
/^https?:\/\//.test('https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket'); // true

/^https?:\/\//.test('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket'); // true

/^https?:\/\//.test('ftp://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/cricket'); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

`(http|https)?:\/\/(\S+)`

This works for me

Not a regex specialist, but i will try to explain the awnser.

(http|https) : Parenthesis indicates a capture group, "I" a OR statement.

\/\/ : "\" allows special characters, such as "/"

(\S+) : Anything that is not whitespace until the next whitespace

Comment: Could you provide more detail how it works? And use `` for code in order to make the answer more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for URL encoded strings too.

```
^(https?)(:\/\/|(\%3A%2F%2F))
```

Answer (score 0):

For uppercases: `/^(https?:\/\/)/i` that works in most regex engine:

Use with ignore case flag i for ignore case / case unsensitive:

**JavaScript:**

```
const pattern = /^(https?:\/\/)/i
```

**Python:**

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^(https?:\/\/)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

**PHP:**

```
$pattern = '/^(https?:\/\/)/i'
```

[Regex DEMO](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/cdac655cb075).

Answer (score -1):

Making this case insensitive wasn't working in asp.net so I just specified each of the letters.

Here's what I had to do to get it working in an asp.net *RegularExpressionValidator*:

```
[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]?://(.*)
```

Notes:

- `(?i)` and using `/whatever/i` didn't work probably because javascript hasn't brought in all case sensitive functionality
- Originally had `^` at beginning but it didn't matter, but the `(.*)` did (Expression didn't work without `(.*)` but did work without `^`)
- Didn't need to escape the `//` though might be a good idea.

Here's the full RegularExpressionValidator if you need it:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revURLHeaderEdit" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtURLHeaderEdit" 
    ValidationExpression="[Hh][Tt][Tt][Pp][Ss]?://(.*)"
    ErrorMessage="URL should begin with http:// or https://" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```