# Regex to check with starts with http://, https:// or ftp://

Tags: java, regex, startswith

I am framing a regex to check if a word starts with `http://` or `https://` or `ftp://`, my code is as follows,

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String test = "http://yahoo.com";
        System.out.println(test.matches("^(http|https|ftp)://"));
    } finally{

    }
}
```

It prints `false`. I also checked stackoverflow post [Regex to test if string begins with http:// or https://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643142/regex-to-test-if-string-begins-with-http-or-https)

The regex seems to be right but why is it not matching?. I even tried `^(http|https|ftp)\://` and `^(http|https|ftp)\\://`

Comment: Why a regex? Why not try to construct a URL or URI and get the protocol from that?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need a *whole input* match here.

```
System.out.println(test.matches("^(http|https|ftp)://.*$"));
```

**Edit**:(Based on [@davidchambers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312785/davidchambers)'s comment)

```
System.out.println(test.matches("^(https?|ftp)://.*$"));
```

Comment: You could also use `(https?|ftp)` if preferred.

Comment: @davidchambers: +1. the goal is to convey that the `matches` method will match the whole input. i'll update your input

Comment: You finished with .*$ Can you please elaborate what does it mean (I understand that it gets the entire line but in plain English, how would you explain .*$ thanks!

Comment: @adhg `$` indicates end of line. `.*` matches any character zero or more times.

Answer (score 35):

Unless there is some compelling reason to use a regex, I would just use String.startsWith:

```
bool matches = test.startsWith("http://")
            || test.startsWith("https://") 
            || test.startsWith("ftp://");
```

I wouldn't be surprised if this is faster, too.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wasn't slower (compared to a compiled regex that is), but have to test to find out.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna do it in case-insensitive way, this is better:

```
System.out.println(test.matches("^(?i)(https?|ftp)://.*$"));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the regex / string parsing solutions are great, but for this particular context, it seems like it would make sense just to use java's url parser:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Taken from that page:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                           + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

        System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
        System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
        System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
        System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
        System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
        System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
        System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
        System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());
    }
}
```

yields the following:

```
protocol = http
authority = example.com:80
host = example.com
port = 80
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
query = name=networking
filename = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
ref = DOWNLOADING
```

Answer (score 1):

test.matches() method checks all text.use test.find()

Answer (score 0):

Add a verification between startsWith and matches.

```
import java.net.URL


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    
    val IMAGE_SERVER = "https://google.com/file/"
    val IMAGE_REG: String by lazy {
        val url = URL(IMAGE_SERVER)
        "^(http|https)://${url.host}${url.path}.*\$"
    }
    
    val regx = Regex(IMAGE_REG)
    println(IMAGE_REG)
    

    var begin = System.nanoTime()
    var aa = IMAGE_SERVER.startsWith(IMAGE_SERVER)
    println("startsWith:"+ (System.nanoTime()-begin))
    println("startsWith:"+ aa)
    
    begin = System.nanoTime()
    aa = IMAGE_SERVER.matches(regx)
    println("matches:"+ (System.nanoTime()-begin))
    println("matches:"+ aa)
    

}
```

startsWith:3755625
startsWith:true
matches:174250
matches:true

matches is 174us,  startswith is 3.755ms

matches is much better than startsWith on performance and code cleanness in the scenario.