# Regex that only captures http/https in plain text

Tags: javascript, regex

I current have `str.match(/(http[^\s]+)/i)` which not only captures link in the content, but also in img tag(src="http...") and anchor tag(href="http...")

How do I modify my regex so that it matches only "http/s" that has no "src=" or "href=" before it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643142/regex-to-test-if-string-begins-with-http-or-https

Comment: May be easiest to just get all text nodes first and search only those but it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: can you put some sample data?

Comment: Maybe parsing HTML with regular expressions isn't a really good idea, and you should get the proper elements, then the text from those elements, before you use a regex ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an additional `\s`. `href` or `src` will not have a whitespace character before the URL. In normal text, there is a whitespace.

```
str.match(/\s(http[^\s]+)/i)
```

Also see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM2xC7/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch links that don't start with an = nor a quote before the http/s:

```
str.match(/[^=\"](http[^\s]+)/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overmatch using simple `http[^\s]+` (=`http\S+`).

I'd suggest to use a regex to match text outside of tags, and whitelist those tags where you allow the text to appear. Here is the regex:

```
/(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/(?!p\b|td|pre))https?:\/\/[a-z0-9&#=.\/\-?_]+/gi
```

`(?!p\b|td|pre)` part is where we add whitelisted tags. The regex won't capture `http://example.com,`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU5rR8/4)