# python 3.4 Google Chrome history

Tags: python, google-chrome

I am really getting stuck on the thing I am trying to make.
I want to make a really simple script to display the history of Google Chrome.
When I use the following lines of code:

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\joey\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History', 'rb')
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

I get the next output, I wil only show a part because it wil be too long otherwise.

```
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x81#\x9cU\n\x00\x81yC\t\x08\x06\x08\x08https://www.google.nl/search?q=de+zigodoom&oq=de+zigodoom&aqs=chrome..69i57.1507j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8de zigodoom
```

How can I just display the websites and not all the x00/x000 output. And how can I show each website on a different row.

```
for d in data:
print(data)
```

Wil something like this easy for loop work?

Comment: At the top of the file it says [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) format.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643142/regex-to-test-if-string-begins-with-http-or-https

Comment: Long story short, the history file is **not** just a flat-text list of websites. Also your `for` loop makes no sense - it's incorrectly indented and why would you print the object you're iterating *over* inside the loop?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome's history is stored in an [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database. Python has supported this out of-the-box through [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) since Python 2.5.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\joey\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM urls")
urls = cursor.fetchall()
print('\n'.join(urls))
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for helping me. 
I am getting the next error: sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: That's because Chrome is using it.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 sometimes Chrome doesn't close and keeps background tasks running. You might be able to make a copy without having write permissions.

Comment: @PeterWood how do you make a copy?

Comment: @Dianne the same way you would copy any file. If you're using python you could use [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). I searched google for "copy a file python" and this was the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-to-copy-files