# Validate URL only "http://" or "https://" at the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex, url, url-validation

I'm trying to validate a string at the beginning with the words "http://" or "https://". Some examples:

http://example.com -> Good

http://www.example.com -> Good

https://example.com -> Good

https://www.example.com -> Good

http:///example.com -> Wrong

http:/www.example.com -> Wrong

https//example.com -> Wrong

I have this regular expression, but it doesn't work well:

```
str.match(/^(http|https):\/\/?[a-d]/);
```

...any help please?

Comment: Try `str.match(/^https?:\/\/(?!\/)/i);` or `str.match(/^https?:\/\/\b/i);`

Comment: Can I ask why the domain name must start with `[a-d]`? In your example you want to accept `w` which comes after `d` yet your regexp only accept `a-d`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to test if string begins with http:// or https://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643142/regex-to-test-if-string-begins-with-http-or-https)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
str.match(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know why people want a regex for every simple thing.  If all you need to do is compare the beginning of a string, it is much quicker to just check for it in some cases, like what you are asking for ("validate a string at the beginning with the words 'http://' or 'https://'"):

```
var lc = str.toLowerCase();
var isMatch = lc.substr(0, 8) == 'https://' || lc.substr(0, 7) == 'http://';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the URL specification but this should work according to your request.

`const URL_REGEX = /^(http|https):\/\/([a-z]*\.)?[a-z]*\.[a-z]{2,}(\/)?$/;`

1. ^(http|https):   --- starts with http: or https:
2. //             --- must include double slash
3. ([a-z]*.)?      --- one optional subdomain
4. [a-z]*.         --- domain name with mandatory.
5. [a-z]{2,}        --- at least two char sub-domain suffix
6. (/)?            --- allow optional trailing slash
7. $                --- denotes the end of the string.

Anything after the trailing slash will make the URL invalid.

`https://example.com/` is valid.

`https://example.com/path/to/page` is invalid.